# Elements won't be pushed to array inside stream()

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

When I try to do `console.log(recommendedTasks)` inside the if condition it works but outside the array remains empty

There is the code I've tried for:

```
    let recommendedTasks = [];
    Task.find({}).stream()
        .on('data', function(task){
            for(let skill of member.skills){
                for(let skill2 of task.skills){
                    if(String(skill) == String(skill2)) recommendedTasks.push(task._id);
                }

            }
        });
    console.log(recommendedTasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but I dont have those privalages.

It should be because the `console.log` is being called in a for loop.

The following code should work.

```
for (i = 0; i < recommendedTasks.length; i++) { 
  console.log(recommendedTasks[i])
}
```

Again I wish I could comment. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you define recommendedTasks outside Task function which triggers at same time as console.log() which takes the first value available [], try this instead.

```
 Task.find({}).stream()
   .on('data', function(task){ 
     let recommendedTasks = [];
     for(let skill of member.skills){ 
      for(let skill2 of task.skills){  
       if(String(skill) == String(skill2)) return recommendedTasks.push(task._id); 
      } 
     } 
   }); 
   console.log(recommendedTasks)
```

Hope it helps.